# This site can’t provide a secure connection displayed how to resolve this error?

Tags: spring-boot, http, authentication, ssl, https

My application based on spring boot and microservices architecture. There is FrontUI, CartService, AuthService microservices.

FrontUI has

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public String getSearch(...){
// code
}
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "login";
}
```

When I type http://localhost:8080/search and hit enter everything is ok search page with products are displayed. But when I hit Login button url changes to https://localhost:8080/login and then

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

error is displayed. 
I tried to remove all data from chrome
I tried to Query HSTS/PKP domain but it found nothing

I think I should configure project with ssl. or not?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried browsing incognito mode? Could you please share the application.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Actually application was redirecting to https://localhost:8080/login because link `<a>` was like `<a href="https://localhost:8080/login">` and it has no chance other than to redirect to https://localhost:8080/login. And error was displayed because I have not configured my spring project with HTTPS. View this link in order to see how to configure https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/ 
Thanks hope this was useful